# Difficulty with nested form for many children using Rails, Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, parent-child, formtastic

Very new to Rails.  I'm trying to create a form using Formtastic in which a user creates many Picks in a single form.  Each Pick belongs to a Game and each Game belongs to a Week.  I'm reasonably certain I've correctly declared these relationships in my models.

The problem: I'd like to create Picks for all of a Week's Games and properly save each child Pick with an index that allows me to associate it with the correct parent Game.

Here is the new.html.erb code for Weeks that makes no attempt to index the Picks.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @week do |f|%>


<%= f.inputs do %>
    <% week_slate.each do |g| %>    
        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :game do |game| %>
            <%= game.inputs do %>
                <%= game.semantic_fields_for :pick do |pick| %>
                        <%= pick.inputs %>
                        <%= pick.input :winner, :as => :radio, :label => "", :collection => [[g.visiting_team, false], [g.home_team, false]]  %>
                        <%= pick.input :wager %>                    
                <% end %>
            <% end %>       
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Edit: week_slate is an array that contains all of the Games that belong to the current Week.

Please advise & many thanks!

Comment: week_slate is an array that contains all of the Games that belong to the Week.  Thanks.